# Select Checkbox on website dropdown.

Tags: excel, checkbox, onclick, vba

I have this:

```
id="ctl32_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl32" type="checkbox" name="ctl32$ctl04$ctl07$divDropDown$ctl32" onclick="$get('ctl32_ctl04_ctl07').control.OnValidValueClick(this, 'ctl32_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00');" /><label for="ctl32_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl32">Product</label></span></td>
```

And I'm trying to select the checkbox.

I've tried everything I can to select it. At one point I got it clicked but it didn't really select it so much as appearing to put a check in the box.

This is something I found and had hopes for but maybe I'm using it wrong.

```
 Set elems = HTMLdoc.getElementById("ctl32_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00")

        For Each e In elems
            If (e.getAttribute("value") = "ctl32_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00") Then
                e.Click
                Exit For
            End If
        Next e
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Please provide context. HTMLdoc within Excel?  What are you doing?

Comment: elems is a single element; not a collection. Just elems.click.

Comment: Yes, it's within Excel. I have a website that I need to input dates and select a cause tag. The dates I can get just fine. The cause tag I can't. Basically, I'm trying to automate a process that will go grab the data off the web page and then import it and continue on with my macro (that works fine). Automation of this step isn't entirely necessary, but would be nice to have and useful when I turn this tool over to others.